# React hook stale closure: setState only triggers twice in callback function of a subscription

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, closures

I' trying to build a toast message API for React. My goal is to provide a `fireNotification()` api that can be called anywhere in the app and have React render the toast component.

I built this simple notification manager with sub/pub pattern and hope to be able to subscribe to new notifications in a `useEffect` hook

```js
const notifications = [];

const listeners = new Set();

function subscribe(callback) {
  listeners.add(callback);
}

function publish() {
  listeners.forEach((cb) => {
    cb(notifications);
  });
}
export function fireNotification(content) {
  notifications.push(content);
  publish();
}

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    subscribe((updated) => {
      setState(updated);
    });
  }, []);

  // state will be logged correctly 2 times
  // won't be updated after that
  console.log("state", state);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => {fireNotification('test')}}>fire</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-snowflake-rk1d9?file=/src/App.js:525-543)

However, `fireNotification()` will only trigger `setState` twice

From the 3rd time onward, the state is not updated at all.

I'm able to make state update work by changing `setState(updated)` to `setState([...updated])`, but not sure why it works.

Can someone explain why `setState(updated);` only triggers twice? Thanks!

Comment: `[...updated]` creates a new instance of an array. Maybe this makes React treat the state as changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide data to watch for changes, to the useEffect

```
React.useEffect(() => {
subscribe((updated) => {
  setState(updated);
});
}, [updated]);
```

Other wise the useEffect will run only twice

Comment: i think you should return a cleanup ini this case. such as `return unsubscribe()` or something at the end before the line of dependency array

Comment: This is wrong. `updated` is not defined outside the subscription function.

Comment: @HadiKAR Not returning a cleanup function shouldn't result in the behavior.